# GUI miners for Private Ethereum Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mining, private-blockchain

I have setup a multinode private Ethereum blockchain with geth. I am using geth miner (`miner.start(thread)` at geth console) for mining blocks but my other nodes users want to use GUI miner instead of geth.

Can anyone help with any suggestions to how to use any GUI miner with private ethereum blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way:

Developed a GUI using **Unity (C#)** that executes geth upon start with the Process class and captures the geth output for an emulated console, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186833/10868780).

Then, if you [enable RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#go), you can send RPC requests to do anything you want with the [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC).

Using Unity you can make builds for Linux, Windows, and Mac. Plus you can quickly and easily make pretty GUIs.